# Using Laplace transform to solve the ODE $DP/dt = P + k(H(t-T)-1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

A population of fish that's growing is harvest at a rate of $k$, from $t = 0$ to $t = T$ and follows the DE:

$$DP/dt = P + k(H(t-T)-1), \qquad P>0$$

How do I solve the IVP with $P(0) = P_0> 0$?  What's confusing me is the Heaviside function $H(t-T)$. I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: "what to do with it" -- take the Laplace transform, as your tag suggests.

Comment: What is the definition of the heaviside function?